# accessing elements of a vector of struct with iterators c++

Tags: c++, vector, struct, iterator

I made the following code:

```
namespace bcra {
    // The value type of a data item.
    using value_t = long;

    /// This class represents a single Bar Chart.
    class BarChart 
    {
        //=== Definition
        public:
            /// Represents a single bar information.
            struct BarItem 
            {
                string label;    //!< Bar label.    
                value_t value;   //!< Bar value.    
                string category; //!< Bar category. 
                BarItem( string l, value_t v, string c ) : label{l}, value{v}, category{c}
                {/*empty*/}   
            };
            
            //== Data members
        public:
            /// The collection of bars items
            std::vector< BarItem > bars;
      };
}

int main()
{

   BarChart m_barChart;
   
   // open file txt
   m_barChart.bars.push_back(...);
   // close file txt
   // ....
   // ....
   // ....
   // creating a vector where I'm going to take a certain range from that main vector.
   std::vector<BarChart::BarItem> bar_s;

   for (auto i{ count_value }; i < (count_value + n_linhas); ++i)
            {
                bar_s.push_back(m_barChart.bars[i]);
                
            }
   // ....
   
   
   // ...
   
   
   // MY PROBLEM
   
    std::vector < value_t>::iterator inicio2;    ??????
    std::vector<value_t>::iterator fim2;       ??????
    inicio2 = bar_s.begin(); ????????
   // 
   // ...

   sort(bar_s.begin(), bar_s.end(), compare);
```

my goal is as follows: m_barChart will have all data from a text file with the following structure (string, int, string),
and what i want to do is create a new vector where i put a range of this larger vector (so far I've been successful), THE BIG PROBLEM is that i want to get this other vector (bar_s) and sort it with an iterator that goes get the integer value, swapping all objects of bar_s[0] (string, int, string) with bar_s[1] (...), if it is bigger.

To do this i need the begin() is only on the integer value (something like => m_bars.begin().value ??) ???? I don't know what to do from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would have been solved by a suitable comparison function in the past but in modern C++ you would use a projection:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/sort